# How to set default external IP address on Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, linux-networking

I have a server that comes with an IP and an extra failover IP.
I tried to set this failover IP as the "default" IP when making requests from anywhere in the OS (wget, curl, other programs, etc), but ended up having no IP at all.

I modified /etc/network/interfaces and added:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address FAILOVER_IP
netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Then when running `ifconfig` I could see that new `eth0:0` interface with the failover IP address.

To set it as the main address, I tried to `route delete 0.0.0.0` and then `route add default eth0:0`. But that made me lose connection to the server and can't access it with any of those addresses.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your default gateway permanently edit `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address <primary-ip>
    netmask <netmask>

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address <secondary-ip>
    netmask <netmask>
    gateway <gw-ip>
    dns-nameservers <dns1>
    dns-nameservers <dns2>
```

If you want to temporarily change your default gateway:

1. Add the new GW: `route add default gw <ip-address> eth0`
2. Delete the old GW: `route add default gw <ip-address> eth0`

Comment: @Ivan, the first example here puts the default gateway on the eth0:1 sub interface.  The name of the interface and which interface is used as the gateway are both customizable.  (i.e. you can set it to eth0:0 if you wish.) You can also route some traffic through one interface and other traffic through other interface(s).  But MarkoPolo's example is basically tuned to the setup you described.

Comment: @MarkoPolo @Xalorous I edited the /etc/network/interfaces and rebooted the server. It then would use eth0:1 as its default interface... If I run `curl --interface eth0` then it would use the new IP

Comment: All credit to @MarkoPolo for his excellent answer.  I only clarified some things that he took for granted. Since I only recently learned about sub-interfaces, I recognize the parts that are probably new to other rusty/newish *nix admins.